filter list data on various parameters in flutter
I have a list of product List<Product> items value are coming in string variable and there is a search from where we can selected multiple parameters like color, shape, size etc. so i want to filter list on various parameters.
DiamondSearchParameters is being used in form, many parameters are multi selection and i want to filter list according to selected parameters. Consider list List<Product> contains api data with string values and in DiamondSearchParameters all are static data for color, shape and etc.
class DiamondSearchParameters extends Equatable {
  late final Set<Shape>? shapes;
  late final SplayTreeSet<CaratRangeItem>? caratRangeItems;
  late final DiamondColor? color;
  late final Set<SearchDiamondFormOption>? colorVariants;
  late final Set<SearchDiamondFormOption>? fancyIntensity;
  late final Set<SearchDiamondFormOption>? fancyOvertone;
  late final Set<SearchDiamondFormOption>? clarity;
  late final DiamondMake? diamondMake;
}

Trying to sort data in this way, want better approach
_getSearchCount(
    DiamondSearchParameters param,
  ) {
    final List<Product> sortedDiamondsList = product!;
    final List<Product> temp = [];
    sortedDiamondsList.forEach((element) {
      param.shapes?.forEach((shapes) {
        if(element.shapeName == shapes.toString()){
          debugPrint('shape---${element.shapeName}');
          temp.add(element);
        }
      });
      if(param.color == element.color){
        debugPrint('color---${element.color}');
      }
      param.colorVariants?.forEach((colorVariants) {
        debugPrint('colorVariants---${element.color}');
      });
    });


You can set up your loop with OR operator
_getSearchCount(
  DiamondSearchParameters param,
) {
  final List<Product> sortedDiamondsList = product!;
  final List<Product> temp = [];
  sortedDiamondsList.forEach((element) {
    if (param.shapes?.any((shape) => shape.toString() == element.shapeName) ||
        param.color == element.color ||
        param.colorVariants?.any((color) => color == element.color)) {
      temp.add(element);
    }
  });

  return temp;
}

